# Derivative of trace and norm

Tags: vector-analysis

I need to find the gradient with respect to $W$ of this equation

$\text{tr}(A’ C^{-\frac{1}{2}} W C^{-\frac{1}{2}} A) + \frac{a}{2} ||W-D+Z/a||_{F}^2$

Where $A, C, W, D$, and $Z$ are matrices, and $a$ is a constant

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, it wouldn't hurt if you would edit the question and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Or/and - why you need to find the gradient... It will make us feel happier to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of typing, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= \left(C^{-1/2}AA^TC^{-1/2}\right)^T \\
Y &= W - D + \frac 1aZ &\quad\implies\quad dY = dW \\
}$$
and let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
B:A &= {\rm Tr}(B^TA) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Write the objective function in terms of these new variables.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= B:W + \tfrac a2(Y:Y) \\
d\phi &= B:dW + \tfrac a2(2Y:dY) \\
  &= (B + aY):dW \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W}
 &= B+aY \\
 &= \left(C^{-1/2}AA^TC^{-1/2}\right)^T + \Big(aW - aD + Z\Big) \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know, which matrix norm is used, let me consider the Frobenius norm here
\begin{align}
||W||_{\text{F}}=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} w_{ij}^2}
\end{align}
Then one can derive these two formulae:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\, \text{tr}(AWC)}{\partial W}=A^{\text{T}}C^{\text{T}},~\frac{\,\partial ||W||_{\text{F}}}{\partial W}=\frac{W}{||W||_{\text{F}}}
\end{align}
by which you can finish your case. The derivation is easy, it follows the rule $\left(\frac{\partial s(W)}{\partial W}\right)_{ij}=\frac{\partial s(W)}{\partial w_{ij}}$ for any scalar function $s$.